# UIButton align image left and center text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, layoutsubviews

**Introduction:**

I have a class, which *inherits* from `UIButton`. In this class I want to *update* properties, like `titleEdgeInsets`, `imageEdgeInsets`, `contentHorizontalAlignment`.

My first approach was to use `layoutSubviews`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // update properties 
}
```

The `layoutSubviews` creates an *infinity loop*, so that I've searched for an alternative method.

**My Question:**

Is it a common way, to use the `willMove` method for *updating* `UIButton` properties?

```
override func willMove(toWindow newWindow: UIWindow?) {
    super.willMove(toWindow: newWindow)

    // update properties
}
```

If not, why?

**My goal is to align the imageView of the button left (with padding) and center the text.**

**UPDATE:**

I need the button frame.size and the bounds.width to calculate the position of the text and the image view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the properties you mentioned above can be set in the `init` of the `UIButton` there is absolutely no need to set them in `layoutSubviews` or `willMove(toWindow`.
`layoutSubviews` will be called multiple times so setting these properties again n agin in here makes no sense. `willMove(toWindow` will be called when button is added to some view and button is loaded but you dont have to wait till then to set these properties. Because you already have a subclass of button, so I would suggest doing

```
class SomeButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

By the way creating a subclass of `UIButton` is not recommended, so if you wanna simply assign these properties to your button you can rather have a extension to `UIButton`

```
extension UIButton {
    func applyStyle() {
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Is this what you want??

[image]

[image]

No matter what the text is, text is always in centre and image is to its left with 10 pixel padding

**EDIT 2:**

As OP has confirmed that, he wants the button to be styled as showed in images above, posting the code to achieve the same

```
class SomeButton: UIButton {
    var titleFont: UIFont! = nil
    var textSize: CGFloat = 0
    let imageWidth: CGFloat = 20
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 30

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.titleFont = titleLabel!.font
        self.setTitle("here", for: .normal)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "hand"), for: .normal)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        if let string = self.title(for: .normal) {
            textSize = string.widthOfString(usingFont: self.titleFont)
            //30 because imageWidth + 10 padding
            return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: textSize + 30, height: buttonHeight))
        }
        return CGRect.zero
    }

    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: buttonHeight))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        //60 because you need eauql padding on both side 30 + 30 = 60
        return CGSize(width: textSize + 60, height: buttonHeight)
    }
}

extension String {

    func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
        return size.width
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't work, because I need the frame size and the bounds width to calculate the position of the button image view and the button text. Sorry, I have updated my question..

Comment: @sean-stayn you can access width and height by let width = self.bounds.width, let height = self.bounds.height lemme know if I am not getting you correct

Comment: @sean-stayn : are you planning to apply dynamic inset based on the button content? and that's why you want to do it `willMove(toWindow`? Using `willMove(toWindow` is not a very efficient way though

Comment: yes, you are right! This is necessary, because I want to center the button text and align the image to the left with a padding.

Comment: @sean-stayn If your requirement is just to centre align text and place image to its left with fixed padding you don't need to know the width in prior gimme a minute lemme update my answer. It would be helpful if you can update a photo/image of the button styling you need

Comment: Sorry, it's a confidential client app. I can't upload any photo. But it would be wonderful, if you can give me a more common solution.

Comment: @sean-stayn: Added an image for your reference, check if thats what you want Ill update my answer with the code for the same

Comment: exactly! this is, what I need

Comment: Gimme a minute I am away from MacBook I'll post it in a while

Comment: I have time... today is sunday... ;) I have given you an upvote, because of your effort! thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, implement both initializers. Don't just fatal error.

Comment: @sean-stayn: Please check

Comment: @Sulthan thank you :) I have updated both the inits as u mentioned :)

Comment: @sean-stayn: Did you try the code ? Did it work for you?